# ERROR: Exhausted all sources trying to fetch version 'latest' of RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, centos, ruby-on-rails-5

I am configuring CentOS 6 Server. i am trying to install rvm but i am getting error. when i try to install rvm in server. Can anyone knows the reason?

step1.

```
 gpg --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
```

OUTPUT

```
gpg: key D39DC0E3: "Michal Papis (RVM signing) <mpapis@gmail.com>" not changed
gpg: key D39DC0E3: "Totally Legit Signing Key <mallory@example.org>" not changed
gpg: key 39499BDB: "Piotr Kuczynski <piotr.kuczynski@gmail.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 3
gpg:              unchanged: 3
```

step 2 (where i get error)

```
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Output

```
WARN: ...the preceeding error with code 35 occurred while fetching https://api.github.com/repos/rvm/rvm/tags
curl: (35) SSL connect error
WARN: ...the preceeding error with code 35 occurred while fetching https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/mpapis/rvm/refs/tags?sort=-name&pagelen=20

ERROR: Exhausted all sources trying to fetch version 'latest' of RVM!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the version of cURL in your server?

This might shed some light: [cURL SSL connect error 35 with NSS error -5961](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887315/curl-ssl-connect-error-35-with-nss-error-5961)

Comment: hey i don't have curl error. i have error during rvm install http://rvm.io/rvm/security

Comment: Well, looking at your output, seems like a cURL error: `curl: (35) SSL connect error` and that's preventing all the connection attempts

Comment: It'd be really cool if the asker told us what he did from this answer that fixed it.