# CentOS6 - curl NSS error -5961 resolved by updating packages. What did it actually do?

Tags: ssl, curl, centos6, nss

I was running into the same issue as described in this question: [cURL SSL connect error 35 with NSS error -5961](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887315/curl-ssl-connect-error-35-with-nss-error-5961)

```
$ curl --verbose https://api.hostname.com                                                                                                                                                                
* About to connect() to api.hostname.com  port 443 (#0)                                                                                                                                                                                
*   Trying 1.2.3.4... connected                                                                                                                                                                                                          
* Connected to api.hostname.com  (1.2.3.4) port 443 (#0)                                                                                                                                                                          
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb                                                                                                                                                                                          
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  CApath: none                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
* NSS error -5961                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
* Closing connection #0                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
* SSL connect error                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
curl: (35) SSL connect error
```

I followed user qingbo's advice after noticing that the server (CentOS 6.5 VM) had not been updated in a while. I ran this command:

```
$ yum update -y nss curl libcurl
```

and then re-ran the curl command and this time I received an expected `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`.

My question is - what did updating the nss, curl and libcurl packages do that fixed the connection issue?

Comment: worked like a charm, on a old centos 6 server